# Give hovering effect to images while using absolute

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

In my react website I'm using tailwind and  I'm trying to display an image that should be "interactive" so I'd like to have some parts that when are hovered should increase a little their size. My idea to do so was to save all the part of my image individually by keeping the same size frame. something like this:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
[![enter image description here][3]][3]
[![enter image description here][4]][4]
[![enter image description here][5]][5]

So that when put all together they could form this that I could be able to transform one by one:

[![enter image description here][6]][6]

I was able to actually recreate the image with this method but I'm having several problem:

1. it doesn't metter what image I'm hovering is always the same that actually increase its size the others don't move at all.
2. The image invade the footer

This is my code right now:

```
import React from "react";
import One from "../assets/1.png";
import Two from "../assets/2.png";
import Three from "../assets/3.png";
import Four from "../assets/4.png";
import Five from "../assets/5.png";

export const Image = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <img
        className="absolute hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        src={Four}
        alt="/"
      />
      <img
        className="absolute hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        src={Five}
        alt="/"
      />
      <img
        className="absolute hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        src={Three}
        alt="/"
      />
      <img
        className=" absolute hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        src={One}
        alt="/"
      />
      <img
        className="absolute hover:scale-105 duration-300"
        src={Two}
        alt="/"
      />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

Footer:

```
  
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-[1240px] mx-auto py-16 px-4 grid lg:grid-cols-3 gap-8 text-gray-300">
    [...]
   
    </div>
  );
};
export default Footer;
```

How can I fix this? Also, is there a better way to do so?
Thanks

1. https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYsDp.png
2. https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9lu9.png
3. https://i.stack.imgur.com/inRdM.png
4. https://i.stack.imgur.com/IREpR.png
5. https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuZyA.png
6. https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFbKA.png

Comment: "it doesn't metter what image I'm hovering is always the same that actually increase its size the others don't move at all." How do you want the others to move when you hover over one of the images? "The image invade the footer" You haven't included this footer you mention, how is this code and the footer related? Perhaps provide a fuller example showcasing the footer interaction.

Comment: Sorry, of course I was meaning that when I pass my mouse hovering the images they don't move. There is actually only one image that moves when hovered. the other when are hovered are still. I've added my footer code that is another compenent

Comment: How is the `Footer` component integrated into the app in relation to the `Image` component?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import One from "../assets/1.png";
import Two from "../assets/2.png";
import Three from "../assets/3.png";
import Four from "../assets/4.png";
import Five from "../assets/5.png";

export const Image = () => {
  const [isHovered, setIsHovered] = useState(false);

  const handleHover = () => {
    setIsHovered(true);
  };

  const handleMouseLeave = () => {
    setIsHovered(false);
  };

  return (
    <div
      className={`relative ${isHovered ? "hover:scale-105 duration-300" : ""}`}
      onMouseEnter={handleHover}
      onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}
    >
      <img className="absolute" src={Four} alt="/" />
      <img className="absolute" src={Five} alt="/" />
      <img className="absolute" src={Three} alt="/" />
      <img className="absolute" src={One} alt="/" />
      <img className="absolute" src={Two} alt="/" />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Image;
```

the :hover pseudo-class in CSS is not supported on parent or ancestor elements. It can only be applied to the element being hovered or its child elements.

Using this code you can manualize the hover function

Comment: In this way all the images increase size no metter which one I'm hovering, what I'd like to have is only an image at time when hovered to increase its size.